# Execute a vector of functions doesn't work when fns are passes as params

Tags: clojure

This code doesn't work as indended:

```
(((fn [& fns]
    (fn [& params]
      (reduce #(%2 %1) params fns)))
  rest reverse)
 [1 2 3 4]) ;; => () instead of (3 2 1)
```

Is there a way to fix it by only change inside `#(%2 %1)`?

I *think* this question is equivalent to: How to convert `(#<core$rest>)` into `(rest)`?

**NOTE:** This is my process to solve http://www.4clojure.com/problem/58 I've seen the other solutions but I was curious about this specific implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try just using `[params]` rather than `[& params]`, so:

```
(fn [params] (reduce #(%2 %1) params fns))
```

The `[& params]` argument was taking a collection `[1 2 3 4]` and wrapping it again, in a `list`, giving `([1 2 3 4])` as the seed for your `reduce` function.

If you wanted to only change inside `#(%2 %1)` then you would need to unwrap `([1 2 3 4])`, but only the first time. You could see if `first` returned a collection, so `(coll? (first %1))`, and then call `(first %1)`, otherwise just leave `%1` as it is. Seems convoluted and won't work for other input data though.

Comment: That is awesome, thank you very much.  I asked for change inside `#(%2 %1)` because I didn't understand `params`, so this solution is perfect.  Also thanks for the clear explanation.